# Why do I keep getting a TypeError: args.sort is not a function?

Tags: javascript

```
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {

  var args = Array.prototype.join.call(arguments);

  function compareNumbers(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  }
  args.sort(compareNumbers);

  return args;

}

getIndexToIns([40, 60], 50);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was thrown simply because `Array.prototype.join` returns a string. In order to convert array-like objects to arrays, you need to use `Array.prototype.slice.call` instead.

Replace

```
 var args = Array.prototype.join.call(arguments);
```

with this

```
 var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

or with [Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```
var args = Array.apply(null, arguments);
```

or with [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```
var args = Array.from(arguments);
```

The cleanest solution is ES6 [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

```
function getIndexToIns(...args) {

  function compareNumbers(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  }
  args.sort(compareNumbers);

  return args;

}

getIndexToIns([40, 60], 50);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `Array.prototype.join.call(arguments);` will return a string rather than an array and `String` doesn't have a sort method.

Replace

```
var args = Array.prototype.join.call(arguments);
```

with

```
var args = Array.apply(null, arguments);
```

Comment: This will also throw the same error. arguments is not an array. Suggest him like `[...arguments].sort(compareNumbers); `

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy you are right, just confirmed https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments